Standard input/output stream in C++ ROS 2 nodes?
I am trying to use std::cin and std::cout inside a function that also creates a ROS node. When doing so, the program gets blocked, but no input is taken or output printed. For output I know you can use Logger, but what is the correct way to get input?
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, ROS 2 Humble.
Edit:
This issue only appears, when launching the node with ros2 launch. When running with ros2 run, the input is taken in as expected.

According to the answer to this github issue this is intended functionality, to control the flow of information, and that makes sense, but sadly I haven't found any workaround.

One good way is to use services. For an example, you create service and you check the value of variable assigned, call service from terminal when program stops, instead of taking a standard terminal input.
If not, try setting output="screen" in the launch file for node argument.

A service is how I have it working now, but I would like to send a string sentence as a request to a service and for it to be in the same terminal as my main loop, as now the service node is launched in a separate terminal. output="screen" is already set
